# ADB content query SMS fail due to TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am trying to do the same thing as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589102/5992617) (read android SMS from adb shell command)

When executing this command:

> adb shell content query --uri content://sms --projection
>   _id,address,body,read,date,type

fail with android.os.**TransactionTooLargeException**

> Error while accessing provider:sms
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException   at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)  at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)  at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:419)
>     at
>   com.android.commands.content.Content$QueryCommand.onExecute(Content.java:535)
>     at
>   com.android.commands.content.Content$Command.execute(Content.java:417)
>     at com.android.commands.content.Content.main(Content.java:605)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)

The Android has root and the command was executed in the root mode. Android version is 5.1.1 and I have tested on two phones.

However, when I did execute the example command

> adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection
>   name:value --where "name='new_setting'" --sort "name ASC"

in [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993247/5992617), it **works well**

I guess it a specific problem of content query for SMS

Info:
Platform: Mac OSX 10.13
Android version: 5.1.1
ADB version:1.0.40